# Strange voice intro/outro "Green Heaven - Demo" Red Hot Chili Peppers

Tags: lyrics

There is a Red Hot Chili Peppers song called "Green Heaven" in their debut album, *Red Hot Chili Peppers.*

In the [demo version of this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6uQzNRI-Yc), called `Green Heaven - Digitally Remastered 02` on Spotify, there is a strange raspy voice that says something in the first 33 and last 36 seconds of the song.

What is being said during this time?

Answer (score 1):

The voice sounds like a [talk box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_box), which is a way of making a guitar seem to pronounce words by channeling the sound through the player's mouth.

According to this similar question on the [RHCP forums](http://forums.redhotchilipeppers.com/index.php?action=printpage;topic=37520.0), the intro is:

> Oh baby, baby,
>   why don't you f*k with me? (x2)
>   it will feel real... real... gooood

I wasn't able to find anyone else's transcription of the outro --this is what I hear:

> How did you [unitelligable]
>   What do you want to do? (x2)
>   Why are you using me?
>   [unintelligible] buy your love
>   [unintelligible]